# How to combine four select queries into one?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have four different select queries.

```
Select A,Round(B) as P,Round(C) as Q,Round(D) as R,Round(E) as S from tb_name1 a Inner Join tb_name2 b on (a.X1 =b.X2 and a.T_KEY=b.T_KEY) where a.X3="something" and a.X4="xyz" and b.X5="1243" GROUP BY A ORDER BY A DESC

Select A,Round(F) as T from tb_name4 a Join tb_name5 b on (a.K1 = b.K2 and a.K3 and b.K4 ) where a.X6="something" and a.X7="xyz1" and b.X8="1233" GROUP BY A ORDER BY A DESC

Select A,Round(G) as Q from tb_name6 a Join tb_name7 b on (a.K5 = b.K6 and a.K7 and b.K8 ) where a.X9="something" and a.X10="xyz2" and b.X11="123" GROUP BY A ORDER BY A DESC

Select A,Round(H) as R from tb_name8 a Join tb_name9 b on (a.K9 = b.K10 and a.K11 and b.K12 ) where a.X12="something" and a.X13="xyz3" and b.X14="1123" GROUP BY A ORDER BY A DESC
```

I have tried on Union but It's not working.I want one output using four queries and the values should be displayed as one after one values like below...

Output:--

```
Column's Name  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5   Column6   Column7 

Row 1          valu1    valu2    valu3     valu4    valu5     valu6    valu7 

Row 2          valu8    valu9    valu10    valu11   valu12    valu13   valu14 

Row 3          valu15   valu16   valu17    valu18   valu19    valu20   valu21
```

Comment: Where do valu1 to valu21 come from?

Comment: the output is what you want to have ?!? if non show the result that you want to see

Comment: @jarlh .Values come  from the tables by four select queries.

Comment: I'm not psychic. You have to describe how!

Comment: You have to join, not union. What is the connecting field between all these queries or tables?

Comment: @jarlh, I want one output from those 4 queries. The three rows will be same for all columns.The last three values come from last three select queries that should be added after column4.

Comment: @Winegarten, I also  tried with 'Join' but ,not working.Only Cross join worked but there was a problem of duplicate value.The Rows are duplicated 12 times.

Comment: Show us the result of each query, and then the combined.